# Turbogears2: analog of django context processors

Tags: python, django, turbogears, genshi

Is there any analog of django context processors in turbogears2?
In tg1 was stdvars, but not in tg2 anymore.

Explaining:
I need to have some template tags, avaible on each page, without obvious declaring in each controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three possible solutions to achieve this.

First you can use `tg.tmpl_context` which is available inside every template as `tmpl_context`.
You can fill the variables inside the `BaseController.__call__` so that they are available everywhere.

Another approach is to register `base_config.variable_provider` inside `app_cfg.py` which must be a function that returns a dictionary of variables that will be available inside any template. Those variables will be overridden from the controller returned ones if there is a name collision, so it is a good way to provide defaults for controller returned variables.

Otherwise in recent versions it is also possible to register the `before_render` hook systemwide using `base_config.register_hook` inside `app_cfg.py` the callback can append and override any template parameter.

Comment: `base_config.variable_provider` is new to me, too!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be the *best* way of doing it but you could add the following to app_globals.Global:

```
from genshi.core import Markup
self.foo = lambda: Markup("<div>my content here!!!</div>")
```

and then in your your templates:

```
${g.foo()}
```

or you could do it via an ajax request...